# tuple with constraint permitted train travel

Tags: algorithm, constraints, scheduled-tasks, cplex, opl

I have a stuck problem, I want to write a **tuple constraint** on the condition that

P_ij ={k in L |k permitted to carry out the trip from I to j}

where k is the locomotive symbol, L is the set of available locomotives and I write, I feel wrong because tuple only has a starting point and destination without mentioning k but data is required only k so how should I fix it. Note that the data is not changed

```
      {string} Node=...;
     {string} Locomotive=...;

      tuple P{
      string i;
      string j;
      string Locomotive;
      };

     {P} Pij =...;

     {string} IJ= {k |k in Locomotive} inter {<i,j,k>| k in Pij}; 

      and My Data
        
       Node={"S","V","K","G","V1","V2","V3","V4"}
       Locomotive={"L1","L2","L3","L4"}
          Pij
              i   j    Pij    
              S   V1   L1   
              V   V2   L2
              K   V3   L3
              G   V4   L4
```

Answer (score 0):

.mod

```
{string} Node=...;
{string} Locomotive=...;

      tuple P{
      string i;
      string j;
      string Locomotivet;
      };

{P} Pij =...;
     
{string} L[i in Node][j in Node]={l | l in Locomotive : <i,j,l> in Pij};

execute
{
  writeln(L["G"]["V4"]);
}
```

.dat

```
Node={"S","V","K","G","V1","V2","V3","V4"};
       Locomotive={"L1","L2","L3","L4"};
          Pij=
              {   
              <S,   V1,   L1>,   
              <V,   V2,   L2>,
              <K,   V3,   L3>,
              <G,   V4,   L4>};
```

gives

```
{"L4"}
```